# Import objective-c initializer as optional

Tags: objective-c, swift

I've got an Objective-C class whose init method may return nil. I've used a bridging header to expose this class to Swift. Unfortunately, I now have the slight problem that Swift has imported the class's initializer as non-failable.

How can I make Swift respect the fact that the Objective-C initializer may fail?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the Nullability features to annotate your Objective-C classes.

```
- (nullable MyObject *)initWithName:(nonnull NSString *)name;
```

More can be found on the Swift blog.

https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=25

Comment: Worked for me - eventually. The exact placement of the nullable/nonnull is pretty bad, and it's never mentioned but you can't do this with just init(), it has to be initWithName().